# The version of the CoreSimulator framework installed on this Mac is out-of-date and not supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, simulator, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane, xcode12.5

When running ui tests via cli/fastlane on macOS Big Sur 12.3.0, Xcode 12.5.0

```
 xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ./MyWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme MyScheme-UITests
```

```
xcodebuild[88311:3500544]  DVTErrorPresenter: Unable to load simulator devices.
Domain: DVTCoreSimulatorAdditionsErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: The version of the CoreSimulator framework installed on this Mac is out-of-date and not supported by this version of Xcode.
Recovery Suggestion: Please ensure that you have installed all available updates to your Mac's software, and that you are running the most recent version of Xcode supported by macOS.
--
CoreSimulator is out of date. Current version (732.18.6) is older than build version (757.5.0).
Domain: DVTCoreSimulatorAdditionsErrorDomain
Code: 3
--
xcodebuild[88311:3500544]  iOSSimulator: [SimServiceContext sharedServiceContextForDeveloperDir:error:] returned nil (Error Domain=DVTCoreSimulatorAdditionsErrorDomain Code=3 "CoreSimulator is out of date. 
Current version (732.18.6) is older than build version (757.5.0)." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=CoreSimulator is out of date. Current version (732.18.6) is older than build version (757.5.0).}). Simulator device support disabled.
```

What needs to be updated?

[It was fixed by tapping "Install components"](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666924?answerId=648561022#648561022) however I need to figure out what exactly will be installed and if it can be done via cli

Comment: I tried deleting Xcode and reinstalling it. I still get the same error.

Comment: I tried running simulator on an older Mac from which I had migrated. It works fine, showing all the devices. It's also running Big Sur. I didn't try Xcode, which is where I get the error. I only need to get the Simulator to work.

Comment: Did you try opening xcode? It should ask you to install components

Comment: As Ted said, I just opened my xcode after the update and clicked on "install" option. After this I tried to build again and all worked fine

Comment: I tried it again after seeing this update and I got the install option as well. Problem fixed. It must have been a OS/Xcode update as it didn't do it before.

Answer (score 7):

As @VictorGazotti said, open Xcode. When it prompts you to install the additional tools, click "Install."

Try the build again.