# CoreSimulator framework Out of Date Error on Xcode Startup

Tags: android, xcode, flutter, ios-simulator

When I start Xcode, I get a spinning wheel (on a 12 core Mac Pro) and then the error message:

> Details
>
> Unable to load simulator devices.
> Domain: DVTCoreSimulatorAdditionsErrorDomain
> Code: 61
> Failure Reason: The version of the CoreSimulator framework installed on this Mac is out-of-date and not supported by this version of Xcode.
> Recovery Suggestion: Please ensure that you have installed all available updates to your Mac's software, and that you are running the most recent version of Xcode supported by macOS.
> --
> Unable to lookup com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService (757.5) in the bootstrap.  This can happen if running with a sandbox profile.  When running with a sandbox profile, /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService.xpc must be owned by root, not group writable, and not world writable.  See rdar://problem/22142915. isXBSChroot(): NO, XBS_IS_CHROOTED: (null)
> Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
> Code: 61
> Failure Reason: Connection refused
> --
>
> System Information
>
> macOS Version 11.4 (Build 20F71) Xcode 12.5.1 (18212) (Build 12E507)
> Timestamp: 2021-07-04T14:12:50-07:00

This is similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332355/the-version-of-the-coresimulator-framework-installed-on-this-mac-is-out-of-date) on stack overflow. Mine is at startup of Xcode and not from a CLI command.

When I set up the Mac Pro, I migrated from an iMac. Xcode runs fine on the iMac. I tried deleting Xcode and reinstalling it to no avail. If the core simulator is part of Xcode then the error message is probably misleading. Given the spinning wheel and then the error, I suspect there's a timeout. I trying to do Flutter development and need the simulator part of Xcode. I've installed the Android SDK and Android Studio on the Mac Pro. They aren't on the iMac.

The message mentions sandbox. I've never set it up and I get the error even if a project isn't open in Xoode. I also get a similar message when I run flutter doctor.

The file mentioned has this cofiguration:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  admin    96B Feb 26 18:46 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService.xpc/
```

This is the same on the iMac where it works fine.

Id look at the problem linked, but a search didn't turn it up.

Comment: Any luck finding the solution yet?

Comment: No new information. I just tried calling Apple Care since I have a contract. They can't help with Xcode issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has gone away probably because of a new version of Xcode or the OS. I started Xcode and it asked to install an extension or the like. After a restart, I ran Xcode and then the simulator. A simulated iPhone appeared.